# Различие между subscribeOn и observeOn методами

Tags: rxjava

В чём заключается различие между `subscribeOn` и `observeOn` методами?

Правильно ли я его понимаю?

Вот то, как я это понимаю: `subscribeOn` определяет поток по умолчанию для `Observable` после его создания (в случае, если его нужно выполнять не в текущем потоке), т.о., начинаться выполнение будет всегда в потоке, определённом `subscribeOn`. И поэтому `subscribeOn` нужен только один (если будет несколько `subscribeOn`, выполнится только первый). А `observeOn` после может поменять поток, начиная с места вызова, и сколько будет `observeOn`, столько раз будет меняться поток.

Comment: [Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/company/rambler-co/blog/280388/) хорошо расписан ответ на ваш вопрос. И, в целом, вы правильно понимаете.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Нашла [полезную статью](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reactive-programming-operators-in-rxjava-20--cms-28396), которая содержит точный ответ насчёт количества и места вызова данных методов. Надеюсь, поможет кому-нибудь ещё.

**По поводу subscribeOn()**

> The subscribeOn() operator will have the same effect no matter where
>   you place it in the observable chain; however, you can't use multiple
>   subscribeOn() operators in the same chain. If you do include more than
>   one subscribeOn(), then your chain will only use the subscribeOn()
>   that’s the closest to the source observable.

Что значит:

> Оператор subscribeOn() будет иметь тот же эффект независимо от того,
>   где вы поместите его в цепочку observable; однако вы не можете
>   использовать несколько операторов subscribeOn() в одной цепочке. Если
>   вы включили в цепочку более одного subscribeOn(), ваша цепочка будет
>   использовать только subscribeOn(), который ближе всего к observable
>   источнику.

`subscribeOn()`, который ближе всего к `Observable` источнику - это первый в цепочке, и данное утверждение было также проверено опытным путём, например, если есть цепочка:

```
observable
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
     .subscribe(observer);
```

то `onNext()` каждого элемента выполняется в потоке `RxNewThreadScheduler-1` (потоке, созданном `Schedulers.newThread()`), а цепочка

```
observable
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())     
     .subscribe(observer);
```

передаёт выполнение `onNext()` каждого элемента в поток `RxComputationThreadPool-1` (поток, созданном `Schedulers.computation()`).

**По поводу observeOn()**

> Unlike subscribeOn(), where you place observeOn() in your chain does
>   matter, as this operator only changes the thread that’s used by the
>   observables that appear downstream.  For example, if you inserted the
>   following into your chain then every observable that appears in the
>   chain from this point onwards will use the new thread.

```
.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
```

> This chain will continue to run on the new thread until it encounters
>   another observeOn() operator, at which point it’ll switch to the
>   thread specified by that operator. You can control the thread where
>   specific observables send their notifications by inserting multiple
>   observeOn() operators into your chain.

Что значит:

> В отличие от subscribeOn(), имеет значение, куда в цепочку вы
>   помещаете функцию observeOn(), так как этот оператор только изменяет
>   поток, который используется observables, которые следуют ниже.
>   Например, если вы вставляете в свою цепочку следующий код, то каждый
>   observable, который появляется в цепочке с этого момента, будет
>   использовать новый поток.

```
.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
```

> Эта цепочка будет продолжать работать в новом потоке, пока не
>   встретится другой оператор observOn(), после чего она переключится на
>   поток, указанный этим оператором. Вы можете управлять потоком, куда
>   конкретные observables отправляют свои уведомления, путём вставки в
>   вашу цепочку нескольких операторов observeOn().